# Visual Studio Installer fails to run

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio installer will not run.

First was trying to install additional feature from Visual Studio. Then running the visual studio installer from start menu.
Then deleting the installer directory and trying to run it from a fresh VS online installer.

Here is the error message from the log

```
Error 0x80131501: Application failed with an uncaught exception: Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.Views.ThemedWindow..ctor(AppInitializerServiceOptions serviceOptions, IApplicationViewModel vm, Nullable`1 parentHandle)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.FocusedUi.Views.FocusedWindow..ctor(AppInitializerServiceOptions serviceOptions, IApplicationViewModel vm, Nullable`1 parentHandle)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.Application.WindowFactory.Create(IInstallerCommandLineOptions commandLineOptions, AppInitializerServiceOptions serviceOptions, IApplicationViewModel viewModel)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.Application.MainApplication.InitializeWindow(AppInitializerServiceOptions serviceOptions, IInstallerCommandLineOptions commandLineOptions, IApplicationViewModel viewModel)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.Application.ApplicationBase.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.Application.MainApplication.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.IApplication.Run()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Installer.Program.ExecuteInternal(IServiceContainer services, ICommandLineParserResult`1 parserResult, ITelemetry telemetry, ILogger logger)
```

Comment: Have you uninstalled it or just deleted the directory?

Comment: deleted the VS installer directory, which doesn't have an uninstall

Comment: Yes there is a uninstall feature. (See link) https://ibb.co/0V0kfSj Maybe that the program setup some variable store in the registry and those are not removed when you delete the directory.